# Keep getting syntax error at the final bracket of my function in PHP

Tags: php, methods, compare

I'm trying to write a method for a Dorm class I created, the method is assign_to_dorm(), which accepts a single argument, which is a student object.

This method should do two things:

Check to see if the number of items in the occupants property array is equal to or greater than the capacity property. If so, return FALSE.
If not, take the student object, and add it as an item in the occupants property array.

```
<?php

class Dorm
{
    private $dorm_name;
    private $capacity;
    private $occupants = array();


   public function assign_to_dorm(Student)
   {
       $ammount = count($occupants);

       if($ammount >= $capacity)
       {
            return FALSE;
       } 


    } //    <---------------  KEEP GETTING ERRORS HERE
}

?>
```

Comment: What is the **full** error message you receive? Also, is this the only code in the file? Syntax errors at the end of the file are often related to problems further up...

Comment: ...and what is the line `public function assign_to_dorm(Student)` about? Surely is should be `public function assign_to_dorm($Student)` - plus, you never seem to use `$Student`, and I'm guessing that `$capacity` should be `$this->capacity`, same goes for `$occupants`...

Comment: the argument which i was trying to pass was another class in the same project called 'Student', i just figured that I could pass it like that, do i have to add a $ at the beginning? I just didnt realize that since i havent declared a $student variable

Comment: How are you intending to use the value you passed in? You can't access it unless it's stored in a variable... This is true of any language I have ever come across...

Answer (score 1):

```
public function assign_to_dorm(Student)
                               ^^^^^^^---- bare word
```

Your parameter is a bare word, which does not work. It should be a variable and/or variable + type hint.

Comment: the argument which i was trying to pass was another class in the same project called 'Student', i just figured that I could pass it like that, do i have to add a $ at the beginning? I just didnt realize that since i havent declared a $student variable

Comment: You can't pass in a class name like that. PHP function parameters must be values of some sort: static values, variables, or the results of function calls. A bare word works too, if it's a define()'d constant, but you can't pass in a class name like that. You'd have to pass in an actual string: `'Student'`.

Answer (score 1):

```
  public function assign_to_dorm($student) //proper variable syntax
   {
       $ammount = count($this->occupants);
       if($ammount >= $this->capacity)  //access members via $this->member_name
       {
            return FALSE;
       } 
    } //
```

You have 2 errors in your function definition:

- the parameter you are passing to the function should be `$student`
- class members should be qualified with `$this`. `$occupants` is a local variable defined in the function scope, `$this->occupants` is the class member.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance In your arguments list for assign_to_dorm you are just providing Student which is the class. Try Student $student, or simply $student.

Comment: the argument which i was trying to pass was another class in the same project called 'Student', i just figured that I could pass it like that, do i have to add a $ at the beginning? I just didnt realize that since i havent declared a $student variable

Comment: That's fine to pass an instance of a student class, but you need to prefix it with a $ which will assign that argument into a named variable, and allow you to reference the value passed into the function as $student.